# Using SQLite Triggers to Preserve Tree Order

Tags: sqlite, triggers, tree

I have a hierarchical tree stored in a table, with each element having a parentID and an 'order' value, which is the order of elements if the tree were flattened into a list. See the following (simplified):

```
CREATE TABLE Section (
    sectionID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    sOrder INTEGER NOT NULL,
    parentID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (parentID) REFERENCES Section (sectionID)
);
```

I wrote some triggers to keep this `sOrder` value accurate.

```
CREATE TRIGGER SectionUpdateOrderOnInsert BEFORE INSERT ON Section
BEGIN
    UPDATE Section SET sOrder = sOrder + 1 WHERE sOrder >= NEW.sOrder;
END;

CREATE TRIGGER SectionUpdateOrderOnUpdateUp BEFORE UPDATE ON Section
WHEN OLD.sOrder < NEW.sOrder
BEGIN
    UPDATE Section SET sOrder = sOrder - 1 WHERE sOrder > OLD.sOrder AND sOrder <= NEW.sOrder;
END;

CREATE TRIGGER SectionUpdateOrderOnUpdateDown BEFORE UPDATE ON Section
WHEN OLD.sOrder > NEW.sOrder
BEGIN
    UPDATE Section SET sOrder = sOrder + 1 WHERE sOrder < OLD.sOrder AND sOrder >= NEW.sOrder;
END;

CREATE TRIGGER SectionUpdateOrderOnDelete BEFORE DELETE ON Section
BEGIN
    UPDATE Section SET sOrder = sOrder - 1 WHERE sOrder > OLD.sOrder;
END;
```

The triggers work... sometimes. For example:

```
INSERT INTO Section VALUES (1, "Part I", 1, 1);
INSERT INTO Section VALUES (2, "Part II", 2, 2);
INSERT INTO Section VALUES (3, "Chapter 1", 3, 1);
INSERT INTO Section VALUES (4, "Chapter 2", 4, 1);
INSERT INTO Section VALUES (5, "Chapter 1.5", 4, 1);
```

works as intended, with the last insert shifting Chapter 2 up to `sOrder = 5`. But the following doesn't work:

```
INSERT INTO Section VALUES (1, "Part I", 1, 1);
INSERT INTO Section VALUES (2, "Part II", 2, 2);
INSERT INTO Section VALUES (3, "Chapter 1", 3, 1);
INSERT INTO Section VALUES (4, "Chapter 2", 4, 1);
INSERT INTO Section VALUES (5, "Chapter 1.5", 3, 1);
```

In this example, Chapter 1 and Chapter 2 retain their original `sOrder` value. I expect them both to be shifted up to 4 and 5 respectively.

What am I missing? Is it my logic, or something I'm doing wrong with the triggers?

Minimal example:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Section;
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS SectionUpdateOrderOnDelete;
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS SectionUpdateOrderOnInsert;
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS SectionUpdateOrderOnUpdateDown;
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS SectionUpdateOrderOnUpdateUp;

CREATE TABLE Section (
    sectionID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    sOrder INTEGER NOT NULL,
    parentID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (parentID) REFERENCES Section (sectionID)
);

CREATE TRIGGER SectionUpdateOrderOnInsert BEFORE INSERT ON Section
BEGIN
    UPDATE Section SET sOrder = sOrder + 1 WHERE sOrder >= NEW.sOrder;
END;

CREATE TRIGGER SectionUpdateOrderOnUpdateUp BEFORE UPDATE ON Section
WHEN OLD.sOrder < NEW.sOrder
BEGIN
    UPDATE Section SET sOrder = sOrder - 1 WHERE sOrder > OLD.sOrder AND sOrder <= NEW.sOrder;
END;

CREATE TRIGGER SectionUpdateOrderOnUpdateDown BEFORE UPDATE ON Section
WHEN OLD.sOrder > NEW.sOrder
BEGIN
    UPDATE Section SET sOrder = sOrder + 1 WHERE sOrder < OLD.sOrder AND sOrder >= NEW.sOrder;
END;

CREATE TRIGGER SectionUpdateOrderOnDelete BEFORE DELETE ON Section
BEGIN
    UPDATE Section SET sOrder = sOrder - 1 WHERE sOrder > OLD.sOrder;
END;

INSERT INTO Section VALUES (1, "Part I", 1, 1);
INSERT INTO Section VALUES (2, "Part II", 2, 2);
INSERT INTO Section VALUES (3, "Chapter 1", 3, 1);
INSERT INTO Section VALUES (4, "Chapter 2", 4, 1);
INSERT INTO Section VALUES (5, "Chapter 0.5", 3, 1);
```

Comment: Both examples work for me.

Comment: I ran the code exactly as above, running only the 2nd set of INSERTs, and still get the wrong ordering. See my minimal example above.

Comment: The issue seems to be the presence of the other triggers. Specifically, the 2nd trigger, SectionUpdateOrderOnUpdateUp. Commenting it out makes the inserts run correctly.

Comment: Yeah, I omitted the other triggers from my test.

Comment: Try creating a view, and using INSTEAD OF triggers. Then you can update the base table without triggering other triggers.

Comment: Ahh, I see. I didn't think about the insert trigger firing the other triggers.

Comment: @CL. Can you elaborate on your suggestion to use views and INSTEAD OF triggers? I can't modify a view, so I'm unsure how this alleviates my problem.

Comment: You can modify a view if you have INSTEAD OF triggers that implement all the needed operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I have actually abandoned my tree structure for now (the db was only part of the problem - writing a model and view to actually display and edit it is another ball game entirely), I still need to maintain the order of the elements in the table. I did what CL. suggested, creating a view and using 'instead of' triggers:

```
CREATE TABLE Section (
    sectionID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    description TEXT NOT NULL,
    sectionOrder INTEGER NOT NULL,
    parentID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (parentID) REFERENCES Section (sectionID)
);

CREATE VIEW SectionView AS SELECT * FROM Section;

CREATE TRIGGER InsertSection INSTEAD OF INSERT ON SectionView
BEGIN
    UPDATE Section SET sectionOrder = sectionOrder + 1 WHERE sectionOrder >= NEW.sectionOrder;
    INSERT INTO Section VALUES (NEW.sectionID, NEW.name, NEW.description, NEW.sectionOrder, NEW.parentID);
END;

CREATE TRIGGER DeleteSection INSTEAD OF DELETE ON SectionView
BEGIN
    UPDATE Section SET sectionOrder = sectionOrder - 1 WHERE sectionOrder > OLD.sectionOrder;
    DELETE FROM Section WHERE sectionID = OLD.sectionID;
END;

CREATE TRIGGER UpdateSectionUp INSTEAD OF UPDATE ON SectionView
WHEN OLD.sectionOrder < NEW.sectionOrder
BEGIN
    UPDATE Section SET sectionOrder = sectionOrder - 1 WHERE sectionOrder > OLD.sectionOrder AND sectionOrder <= NEW.sectionOrder;
    UPDATE Section SET name = NEW.name, description = NEW.description, sectionOrder = NEW.sectionOrder, parentID = NEW.parentID WHERE sectionID = NEW.sectionID;
END;

CREATE TRIGGER UpdateSectionDown INSTEAD OF UPDATE ON SectionView
WHEN OLD.sectionOrder > NEW.sectionOrder
BEGIN
    UPDATE Section SET sectionOrder = sectionOrder + 1 WHERE sectionOrder < OLD.sectionOrder AND sectionOrder >= NEW.sectionOrder;
    UPDATE Section SET name = NEW.name, description = NEW.description, sectionOrder = NEW.sectionOrder, parentID = NEW.parentID WHERE sectionID = NEW.sectionID;
END;
```

Now, when I want to update the order, I call INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE on the view, rather than the actual table.